# Find if a string is in a Pandas range

Tags: python, pandas, comparison

I am trying to figure out a way to separate values stored in a dataframe column depending on if values fall within a pre-defined range. The column is of `object` datatype and contains characters and integers. Here is an example of the data:

```
      code
0     C92.20
1     C80
2     C12.30
3     C18.5
4     C40.5
5     E66.01
6     C78.5
7     L73.2
8     D46.22
9     N18.3
10    N18.5
11    M34
12    M37
13    N18.8
```

I was wondering how could I separate the values between C00-C99 or between N18.3-N18.6 and write it to a new dataframe. Doing this comparison on an integer column is pretty easy but this data has a mix of characters and integers so I have no idea how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex to separate your letters and numbers, which would then allow you to apply your numeric calculations as usual:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['C92.20','C80','C12.30','C18.5','C40.5','E66.01','C78.5','L73.2','D46.22','N18.3','N18.5','M34','M37','N18.8']})

df[['Let', 'Num']] = df['code'].str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]+)([\d\.]+)', expand=True)
df['Num'] = df['Num'].astype(float)
```

This returns the following dataframe:

```
      code Let    Num
0   C92.20   C  92.20
1      C80   C  80.00
2   C12.30   C  12.30
3    C18.5   C  18.50
4    C40.5   C  40.50
5   E66.01   E  66.01
6    C78.5   C  78.50
7    L73.2   L  73.20
8   D46.22   D  46.22
9    N18.3   N  18.30
10   N18.5   N  18.50
11     M34   M  34.00
12     M37   M  37.00
13   N18.8   N  18.80
```